# retriving data from html table

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html table that is filled from a database.
I have a column that have this 2 "buttons"

```
<a onclick="modifica()" href="#" title="modifica"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
<a onclick="delete()" href="#" title="elimina"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
```

P.S: `fa fa-edit` and `fa fa-thresh` are from Font Awesome.

anyway, when i click one of them, i need the function retrieve data from table and read the column ID, but with some tests i've done, i didn't get the result that i want.
someone can help me?

thanks.

Comment: show more code..

Comment: "but with some tests i've done, i didn't get the result that i want.". Please give some examples of the expected output and the current output

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possibilities. But if i understood your problem correctly you could print the ID in your row or directly to your function for every row.

```
<a onclick="modifica(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)" href="#" title="modifica"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

Something like this. Or you could add a data value to your row with `data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"`. Then use javascript so get the next parent data value. Then you have the ID and you can work with it.

Data Attributes:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

JQuery data:

https://api.jquery.com/data/

So i hope i understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify whatever code generates your HTML to either include the ID you need inside the called function, like:

`onclick="modifica(2056)"` - 2056 is whatever ID your `modifica` function requires to work

of add an id to the clickable elements:

```
<a onclick="modifica()" href="#" title="modifica" id="2056"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

and have `modifica` use `javascript` to read the ID of the calling element.

The same applies to the `delete` function as well.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways:

1.- As suggested, if you have the chance to assign the row ID as an attribute to the buttons, you can pass that attribute with `onclick` method to your JS function.

2.- If you CAN'T assign the row ID to the buttons, then you can add some jQuery selectors to your JS function to retrieve the value:

```
 <a onclick="modifica(this)" href="#" title="modifica"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

and in your JS file:

```
 function modifica(button){
   var id = $(button).parent().parent().attr("id");
   //Do Something Else with ID
 }
```

The first parent is `<td>` and the second is `<tr>`.